# Angular Material toolbar not working correctly on mobile

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular Material and tried to create my first Application with it, but the mat-toolbar is not working correctly on mobile.

Thats how it should look like:
[image: correct toolbar]

But It looks like this on mobile:
[image: mobile toolbaar]

As you can see the toolbar is not covering the full width of the screen.

You can try it yourself on my website http://debalator.de

I tried it on a new website without an image inside the body, but the problem is still the same.

[image]

Navbar.html

```
<mat-toolbar class="navbar">
  <span id="title">Erebos</span>
  <span>
    <a mat-button routerLink="home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    <a mat-button routerLink='dice' routerLinkActive="active">Dice-CLI</a>
  </span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <span class="rightnavbar">
   <a mat-button routerLink='login' routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Navbar.css

```
.active {
   text-decoration: underline;
 }

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#title {
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<pe-navbar></pe-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<pe-footer></pe-footer>
```

Comment: Please consider providing the source code of your website _within_ the question itself - see [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the toolbar, it is the overflow, the image has a height of 500px, in addition the footer text exceeds the same

```
 .mat-app-background {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and you can see the problem

Comment: I edited my question and added some more information. It looks like that the image is not causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay I fixed it, had to add "position: fixed" to my body.